# Como hago una gráfica para comparar dos columnas de valores?

Tags: python, pandas, graph

Estoy atragantándome a la hora de graficar dos columnas de datos, una para cada eje, con el fin de compararlas. Si las columnas fueran iguales, obtendría un gráfico con una línea de pendiente 1.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes utilizar la librería seaborn para graficar y con ayuda de pandas extraes los datos:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Suponiendo que tu tabla la guardaste en variable *mi_tabla*
plt.figure()

sns.lmplot(x="sog", y="speed", data=mi_tabla)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!